# setState of react won't rerender

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, render, setstate

This code is supposed to rerender after updating to the state, but that isn't happening
sadly it isn't the case

the @state get successfully updated but the rerender is missing

in data[key].data is a array of objects that gets added to array state[key]

```
$.get url, {t: key, o: @state[key].length, l: @state[key].length + @state.defaultAmount}, (data) =>
  if key == "allScores"
    data.allScores = data.allScores.data[@props.currentMode]
  $.each data[key].data, (i, o) =>
    @setState (state) =>
      result = {}
      result[key] = state[key].concat(o)
      result
```

Comment: are you sure you are calling setState correctly? it looks like you are using a callback function after state is set to build your result object

Comment: I think you're losing your `this` value inside the `$.each` and `$.get`. I don't know coffeescript but you probably need to bind some `this`es

Answer (score 0):

If @state gets successfully updated one time, then my best bet would be that React doesn't see any change in `@state` values to trigger a `re-render`.

Inspect the values of properties of `@state` to see if indeed there is a change.